# django - queryset.last() not returning right order / last record

Tags: django

Writing code that is generating JSON. The last section of JSON has to be terminated by a ",", so in the code I have:

-- Define a queryset to retrieve distinct values of the database field:

```
databases_in_workload = DatabaseObjectsWorkload.objects.filter(workload=migration.workload_id).values_list('database_object__database', flat=True).distinct()
```

-- Then I cycle over it:

```
    for database_wk in databases_in_workload:
        ... do something
        if not (database_wk == databases_in_workload.last()):

                job_json_string = job_json_string + '} ],'
        else:
            job_json_string = job_json_string + '} ]'
```

I want the last record to be terminated by a square bracket, the preceding by a comma. But instead, the opposite is happening.

I also looked at the database table content. The values I have for "database_wk" are user02 (for the records with a lower value of primary key) and user01 (for the records with the higher value of pk in the DB). The order (if user01 is first or last) really doesn't matter, as long as the last record is correctly identified by last() - so if I have user02, user01 in the query set iterations, I expect last() to return user01. However - this is not working correctly. 
What is strange is that if in the database (Postgres) order is changed (first have user01, then user02 ordered by primary key values) then the "if" code above works, but in my situation last() seems to be returning the first record, not the last. It's as if there is one order in the database, another in the query set, and last() is taking the database order... Anybody encountered/solved this issue before? Alternatively - any other method for identifying the last record in a query set (other than last()) which I could try would also help. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Generating json by hand is just a complete WTF - there's a `json` package in the stdlib that knows how to serialize Python to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is behaving the way it does is because there is no ordering specified. Try using `order_by`. [REF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first)

From: `queryset.first()`

> If the QuerySet has no ordering defined, then the queryset is automatically ordered by the primary key

From: `queryset.last()`

> Works like first(), but returns the last object in the queryset.

If you don't want to use `order_by` then try using [queryset.latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#latest)